# No funciona input type="submit"

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tenia un formulario en php para mandar un mail de contacto simple pero de un dia para otro me dejo de funcinonar el boton de submit, no se que cambie y busque por un montón de lugares y no puedo resolver
este es mi codigo:

```
<?php   include 'correo.php'; ?>
<form method="POST" action="correo.php" class="form-contacto">
   <p>Ingresa tu Nombre y Apellido </p> 
   <input class="input-form1" type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="name" required="">

    <p>Ingresa tu correo Electronico </p> 
    <input   class="input-form2" type="mail" placeholder="Ingresa tu mail" name="email" required="mail">

    <p>Ingresa el Asunto de tu consulta</p> 
    <select name="asunto" id="">
        <option disabled selected>Escoger un asunto</option>
        <option value="sueldos">Liquidacion de sueldos</option>
        <option value="general">Contabilidad general</option>
        <option value="Tributarios">Tributarios</option>
        <option value="Programa">Programa de emergencia del trabajo</option>
        <option value="Otros">Otros</option>
    </select>

    <textarea placeholder="Ingresa más informacion sobre tu consulta" name="msg" required=""></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="form-env" value="Enviar" id="enviado" name="enviar">
</form>

<?php
```

y donde lo incluyo, donde hago la funcionalidad es este, aqui recibo los datos que supuestamente se mandan por post pero si no me deja apretar el input de submit no se van a enviar. `utf8_decode(file_get_contents("/Correo.html"));` es lo que se va a mandar dentro del mail, es un html para que se vea mejor

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['asunto']) && !empty($_POST['msg']) ){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['msg'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $header = 'From: mail@mail' ."\r\n";
        $header.= utf8_decode(file_get_contents("/Correo.html"));
        $header.= str_replace('{{mail}}',$asunto , $mensaje);
        $destinatario = $email;

        mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $header);
        if (mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $header)) {

            echo 
            "<script>
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'ENVIADO!',
                    text: 'El correo se ha enviado correctamente, recibira un correo de notificación, le responderemos dentro de las 24hs hábiles',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok!'
                  });
            </script>"; 
            }else{
                echo 
            "<script>
                Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'ERROR!',
                text: 'Debes llenar todos los datos del formulario'
               });
            </script>"; 
            }
    }
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: Quieres decir que tu botón está deshabilitado?

Comment: lo apreto y no se manda ni me sale la notificacion, me deja presionarlo pero no se envia

Comment: El `include('correo.php')` no debería ir.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Revisa el css de tu button tienes tremendo reguero de ids y class. Si tienes alguna logica de disable o enable despues de hacer click puede que lo estes desactivando por css.

Comment: Te faltan los `id` en los inputs, no hace nada porque el primer `if` busca si está seteado el nombre, comprueba agregando un else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví era una clase que estaba puesta en javascript que como tenia un event.preventDefault() no me dejaba apretarlo